# Two string reference are referring to same string but when comparing, result return false.

Tags: java, string

The value of s2 and s3 is "ab" and this string is stored in string pool.
As per doc s2==s3 should return true but it is returning false.
Why?

```
 public class Sample {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      String s="a";
      String s1="b";
      String s2=s+s1;
      String s3="ab";
      System.out.println(s2==s3);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `String s2=s+s1;` stores the result in the string pool? It does not.

Comment: try `(s+s1).intern()`

Comment: Bit of advice: forget about the String pool.  There is nothing to be gained by correct understanding of its workings and everything to lose by incorrect understanding.

Comment: @ScaryWombat happens :)

Comment: @Downvoters Why the downvotes? A perfectly sound and non-trivial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Java Language Specification [§15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> **15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator `+`**
>
> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string
>   conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
>   string at run time.
>
> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object
>   that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters
>   of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand
>   operand in the newly created string.
>
> ***The String object is newly created*** ([§12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)) unless the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).

`+` will always produce a new string, unless the expression is constant. One example of a constant expression is `"a" + "b"`. Your expression is not constant because it contains non-final variables.

This is stated even more clearly in §12.5:

> Execution of a string concatenation operator + (§15.18.1) that is not
>   part of a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) always creates a new String
>   object to represent the result.

Comment: Technically, if the variables were constants, the expression would still be a constant expression.

Comment: @kumesana Variables are variables, constants are constants. But I get you. Corrected.

Comment: Not according to Java. As far as Java is concerned, a constant is, among other things, a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Sure both s2 and s3 equal to `"ab"`.

And sure the `"ab"` String is into the String pool, because you had that String as a literal in your code. Which also means that s3 is taken from the String pool since you're assigning the said literal to it.

But why would you think that `s + s1` would pull the resulting String out of the String pool? It wouldn't.